# What topics does Kinect publish?

Tags: ros, kinect, pointcloud, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am thinking in buying a Kinect in order to implement an AMCL algorithm.
Which topics does kinect offer?
PointCloud or depth Image?

If you are working with it I would really appreciate your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191525/what-topics-does-kinect-publish?/) by [arenillas](https://answers.ros.org/users/15376/arenillas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 223 on 2014-08-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can access to PointCloud, Depth image and RGB image. You can use [openni_launch](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch) to bring up the topics you need.

---

Originally posted by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) with karma: 808 on 2014-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3